# ESXi 5.5 crash on passthrough

Tags: vmware-esxi, adaptec, passthrough

HW: whitebox i7-4771 on gigabyte Z87X-UD5H, Adaptec 6085H sas controller

VT-d and VT-x enabled in bios.

Problem:

Freshly installed ESXi 5.5 update 1
Mark sas controller for passthrough, reboot host.
Create VM, add sas controller, boot VM.
Sas accessible in guest, upon reboot of guest, host crashes.
From that point on, attempting to boot the guest will crash the host every time, and a hard reset is needed.

I'm at my whit's end here...

Comment: Whitebox = not on the VMware HCL?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the passthrough controller? PCIe passthrough is a tenuous solution in the first place. Doing it with hardware that's not on the HCL is asking for trouble. It barely works with fully-certified gear.